# What does %h mean in SSHD configuration?

Tags: configuration, sshd

I'm setting up OpenSSH on a server and I've created my keys on my client, but I don't know where I'm supposed to put the public key on the host. I understand it needs to be added to the `authorized_keys` file, but where is the authorized keys file? In `sshd_config` it has it at

```
%h/.ssh/authorized-keys
```

I look around a bit and I've seen people refer to %h as being a shortcut for the home directory, but is it home directory as in `/home/.ssh` or is it `/home/user/.ssh`?

Forgive my ignorance and thank you in advance!

The .ssh directory is at neither locations, I already looked.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [`man 5 sshd_config`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/sshd_config.5):

> %h is replaced by the home directory of the user being authenticated

This means the file will be `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys`. If the `.ssh` directory is missing (which seems normal if not previously configured) you can create it and also the `authorized_keys` file within and then populate the file's contents with your public key.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have my public key on a flash drive i have mounted at /media/usb and i tried to run this command to create and add the key to the authorized_keys file.

sudo cat /media/usb/id_rsa.pub >> /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys

however, that give me a permission denied error

-bash: /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys: Permission denied

Whats with that? & how would I go about creating this authorized_keys file? Any particular file format or something?

Comment: If creating it yourself (or even if not) make sure you give correct permissions, 700 for the .ssh directory and 600 for authorized_keys

Answer (score 0):

The `%h` placeholder can have one of two (unrelated) meanings, depending on where it is used in configuration for **sshd** (deamon/server)  or **ssh** (client).

The [man page for **sshd_config(5)**](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#TOKENS) documents `%h` as the file path to your home directory, and is accepted by multiple keywords relating to files and directories:

> **TOKENS**
>
> Arguments to some keywords can make use of tokens, which are expanded at runtime:
>
> - [..]
> - `%h` - The home directory of the user.
> - [..]
>
> AuthorizedKeysCommand accepts the tokens %%, %f, **%h**, %k, %t, %U, and %u.
>
> AuthorizedKeysFile accepts the tokens %%, **%h**, %U, and %u.
>
> AuthorizedPrincipalsCommand accepts the tokens %%, %F, %f, **%h**, %i, %K, %k, %s, %T, %t, %U, and %u.
>
> AuthorizedPrincipalsFile accepts the tokens %%, **%h**, %U, and %u.
>
> ChrootDirectory accepts the tokens %%, **%h**, %U, and %u.

The [man page for **ssh_config(5)**](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#TOKENS) documents `%h` as the specified hostname in the `ssh` command.

> **TOKENS**
>
> - `%h` - The remote hostname.
>
> [..]
>
> `HostName` accepts the tokens %% and %h.

This is commonly used to create shortcuts on the command-line. See also https://superuser.com/q/503687/164493.